# no visibility specified.i don't know where is the trouble

Tags: solidity

The following code gives me a `no visibility specified` error:

```
pragma solidity^0.8.7;

contract baga{

   bytes public name =new bytes (2);
   function  initname (){
     name[0]=0x7a;
     name[1]=0x68;

   }
   function getlength() view public returns (uint){
     return name.length ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `initname` needs to be marked as `public`, `private`, `external`, or `internal`. These 4 are the 'visibility' that the error message is talking about. You can read more about these in the docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#function-visibility-specifiers).

I suspect you need to call this function from outside the contract, if that's the case, it'll need to be `public` or `external`. (The difference between those two is that `public` can *also* be called from inside the contract, whereas `external` can *only* be called externally.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no visibility specified in your init function

```
   function  initname (){
     name[0]=0x7a;
     name[1]=0x68;

   }
```

so add a visibility to it, like this:

```
   function initname internal (){
     name[0]=0x7a;
     name[1]=0x68;

   }
```